# How to get the element by css of the pdf icon, protractor testing

Tags: css, angularjs, protractor

I have a pdf image inside the anchor tag.I need to get the element and with that I need to click on the pdf link. Tried with element by Id but getting element not visible but it is visible.Kindly help in getting the element through css,struck in this for nearly 2 days.

```
<div class="az content-block">

            <ol>
                <li>{{'check.ant.label'|text}}</li>
                <li>{{'check.bed.label'|text}}</li>
                <li>{{'check.hin.label'|text}}<a id="checkPdfLink" ng-href="{{check.pdf}}" target="_blank"><span class="az icon-pdf"></span></a></li>
            </ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with css Selector? If it is hard to find a unique ID, try right click on the inspect element of the pdf link and click on Copy Unique Selector and try to click on it.

```
element(by.css('paste your Unique Selector here')).click();
```

Hope this helps. :)

[image]

Comment: Tried this its not working getting element not visible err but the pdf is visible. element(by.css('.az.icon-pdf'));

Comment: Are you sure .az.icon-pdf is the unique selector you've got? Did you get it by right clicking on the inspect element of the pdf? because, most of the time this method works for me. :)

Comment: Can you add an image of your app? So, I can be more helpful. :)

Comment: image is just a pdf icon image

Comment: Ok. Tell me how you got the css selector of the image. :)

Comment: <span class="azfs icon-pdf"></span>

Comment: when I try to inspect tht image, the above class is what i got

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106334/discussion-between-user1645290-and-no-nameeee).

Answer (score 0):

In a simple case, this is just:

```
element(by.id("checkPdfLink")).click();
```

But, since you are getting the "Element not visible" error, there could be several reasons for that. One, is that you may *need to actually do something to make the element visible* - open up a menu, or a dropdown. The other reason, could be the timing problem. Wait for the link to [become clickable](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions.prototype.elementToBeClickable) before clicking:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var pdfLink = element(by.id("checkPdfLink"));
browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(pdfLink), 5000);  // wait up to 5 seconds

pdfLink.click();
```

Comment: Now it is getting timed out after 5 seconds.Its unable to get the element alecxe.

Comment: @user1645290 then, the element is not getting clickable/visible. There cold be multiple reasons for that. Are you sure you are doing everything prior to clicking the link to make the link actually clickable/visible - open up the necessary menu, dropdown, for example?

Comment: its just pdf icon which will be visible directly when we load the html.If you can see the code above I am trying to click the pdf which is present inside the anchor tag.

Comment: @user1645290 quick check - what if you would put `browser.driver.manage().window().maximize()` in the beginning of your test, or into `onPrepare()` - does it make any difference?

Comment: Its not working alecxe. I have a doubt here, actually pdf icon is generated through css class and then the pdf icon will be clickable using the anchor tag so whether we need to get the element of the pdf icon or the anchor link Id to click.